# Can't understand lower bound function with comparator

Tags: c++, stl, lower-bound

I am not able to understand why I am getting an output of 200 whereas by making my own compare function I have reversed the conditions and output should be 100.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool compare(int a,int b){
    return a<=b;
}

int main(){
    int arr[]={1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200,500,2000};
    int key=120;
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);

    int lb=lower_bound(arr,arr+n,key,compare)-arr;
    int x=arr[lb];
    cout<<x<<endl;
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: lower_bound returns an iterator pointing to the first element that doesn't compare lower than the searched-for value. `100 <= 120`, `!(200 <= 120)`, it returns a pointer to `200`. Why would the output be 100?

Comment: You didn't reverse the condition, but your comparison function is broken - it will fail when you search for an exact match.

Answer (score 2):

> whereas by making my own compare function I have reversed the conditions

That's not what your `compare` does. You have just changed the comparison, but in a way that still makes `200` be the first element for which `compare` returns `false`.

If you want to get `100`, you can use `std::prev` to get the previous element pointed at by `lower_bound`:

```
auto it = std::prev(lower_bound(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),key), 1);
```

and now `*it` will be `100`.

If you want the index of this element, you can use `std::distance` like this:

```
int index = std::distance(std::begin(arr), it);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rxsdh6).

Note that you should account for the fact that `lower_bound` may return an iterator to the beginning of the range, in which case, you can't do `std::prev` on it.

Comment: Also while it doesn't affect the functionality of the code, because `lower_bound` is returning an iterator, you don't need to go through pointer arithmetic and then array access. You can just dereference the return value or `std::prev` of the return value or what have you, unless you also want the array index specifically. (It's not used in the asker's code sample, but may be relevant for their full application.)

Comment: @NathanPierson Good point. I separated out the iterator, and the index, so OP can use what is appropriate.